# Hyperlinks and Icons LaTex

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to insert a link say `https://google.com` into a font awesome icon say `\faHome`

How do I do this using the hyperref package? I researched but I cant find any info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\href` is your friend:

```
\href{https://google.com/}{\faHome}
```

Comment: If I use two of these, this creates an odd space between the icons. How does one fix this? Ie 2 links side by side

Comment: @Bana Then, do not insert the space (comment line ends, ...).

Comment: I'll show an example soon once I try to debug it myself lol

Comment: @Bana: …and welcome to TeX.SX!